# Git: Test combination of two feature branches

Tags: git, branching-strategy

I have a Git branch for each feature. However, sometimes, when developing in branch `A`, I would like to test how `A` would behave if `B` was applied also.

At the moment, I use this:

```
git checkout A
git branch base
git merge B
git reset --mixed base
git branch -D base
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Additionally: what if `A` and `B` do not share the same ancestor?

```
o -- o -- o [A]
 \-- x -- o [v1_0]
           \ -- b1 -- b2 -- o [B]
```

How could I do something like this more easily?

```
git checkout A
git branch ABase
git cherry-pick v1_0..B   // only applying b1,b2 not x
git reset --mixed ABase
git branch -D ABase
```

Comment: `git merge v1_0..B`? Don't you mean `git cherry-pick v1_0..B` instead?

Comment: @Jubobs: Yes I will change it to cherry-pick. Also I reset to A afterwards

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
$ git checkout $(git rev-parse A)
$ git merge B
$ git checkout - # returns you to wherever you were before
```

This checks out the underlying revision (leaving you in a detached HEAD state) and makes changes from there. The benefit of this approach would be that you no longer need to create and delete a branch. This doesn't make the workflow much shorter but you should be able to wrap this in a function, take a few arguments, and reuse it.

As for your second question: you should be able to use [`merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to determine the common ancestor(s) and use that to either merge or cherry-pick commits (thinking back to having a function that does this work for you).